# method fetch post slowly adds me information to the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I do fetch post, the application is slow. I enter react developer tools and see how after adding you have to wait about 1 second before the appropriate ID is added to the PointId state .. what can this be caused by?
after completing the form and clicking the confirmation button:

```
 appendElement = (Name, Description, X, Y, RouteId) => {
        const newItem = {
            "Name": Name,
            "Y": Y,
            "X": X,
            "RouteId": 1,
            "Description": Description
        }
        fetch("http://api/Points", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newItem)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    PointId: [...this.state.PointId, res.Id]
                })
                alert("dodales")
            })
        this.setState({
            elements: ([...this.state.elements, { Name, Description, X, Y, RouteId }]),
        })
```

render method:

```
<button className="btn" onClick={() => this.appendElement(this.state.Name, this.state.Description, this.state.Y, this.state.X, this.state.RouteId)}>Dodaj punkt</button>
```

Comment: perhaps the request is what's taking that long? have you looked at he timing of the request

Comment: yes, the request takes quite a long time, how to fix it?